# Muramana active with Ryze Ultimate

Tags: league-of-legends

**Ryze Q and W proc the Muramana active (if toggled), causing them to deal more damage.
Does this extra damage cause more "splash damage" when his ultimate is active?**

[**Muramana Active:**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Muramana)

> Single target spells and attacks (on hit) consume 3% of current Mana to deal bonus physical damage equal to twice the amount of Mana consumed.

[**Ryze - Desperate Power (Ultimate):**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ryze)

> Ryze becomes supercharged, gaining spell vamp and 80 bonus flat movement speed, and causing his spells to deal 50% of their damage to other enemies in a 200 unit radius around the original target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muramanas extra damage won't work with ryzes ultimate because it's AOE.

Desperate Power doesn't really make his spells AOE but it rather **triggers a completely new spell** each time an enemy is hit by one of his abilities. This new spell will only benefit from the spell damage itself and not from on-spell effects like Muramana or Frostfang passive. (The Frostfang passive will still be applied but the original damage won't benefit from it)

The only abilities that will apply the Muramana passive are his Q and W since these are single target spells.

The main target of the singletarget spell will still take the additional Muramana damage though.

Answer (score 0):

- Muramana's damage is not splashed during Desperate Power.
- The bonus damage from Muramana is physical and will not benefit from Ryze's MR reduction and penetration.

[Strategy Wiki - Build Usage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ryze/Strategy)